# Simple Nesting Question

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a a class:

```
.header { background-color: #233574}
```

I want to to style h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 within my class only. I thought that this was writteng like so:

```
.header{}
.header h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 { color: #FFFFFF} //Style these elements within the .header class

<div class="header">
<h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? The h elements are still not pickign up the style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing will style only `h6` tags that are within `h5` tags that are within ... and finally nested within `.header`. If you want to style each heading separately, you need to do something like this:

```
.header h1, .header h2, .header h3, .header h4, .header h5, .header h6
    { color: #FFFFFF} //Style these elements within the .header class
```